# Getting rid of brackets in strings

Tags: export, string-manipulation

I'm very new to mathematica and need help writing to a text file without brackets around my lists of numbers.

Currently in the text file my output is like

```
{"100000000101"}
{"100000000101"}
{"100000000110"}
{"100000000110"}
{"100000000111"}
{"100000000111"}
```

And I would like the brackets and quotation marks to disappear. The vector representing the data is 'a' below and is generated in lines like

```
signedBinary[x_] := IntegerDigits[Mod[x + 2^12, 2^12], 2, 12];

a[[i, 1, j]] = StringJoin@*Map[ToString]@*signedBinary /@ {a[[i, 1, j]]};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show what `a` was supposed to be, so I'm taking a stab in the dark here. But first, let's modify `signedBinary[]`:

```
SetAttributes[signedBinary, Listable];
signedBinary[x_Integer] := IntegerString[Mod[x + 2^12, 2^12], 2, 12]
```

Then, to get a list without the unnecessary characters:

```
nums = Range[-4, 4];
ExportString[signedBinary[nums], "List"]
   "111111111100
    111111111101
    111111111110
    111111111111
    000000000000
    000000000001
    000000000010
    000000000011
    000000000100"
```

Use `Export["filename.txt", signedBinary[nums], "List"]` if you want to output to a file instead.

Comment: Changing the signedBinary function to Integer String solves the problem!
Thanks so much for your help